# Change location of Google Chrome notification message

Tags: windows, google-chrome, notifications

Is there any way to change the location of Google Chrome notification message?

It was used to display on the top-right edge of my screen. Suddenly it started to show the notifications always in the top middle of screen (not exactly in the middle).

[image: Chrome notification Screenshot]

How can I change it back to the top-right corner? I'm using Windows 8.1 OS

Comment: The changes were done few releases ago and for now there's no option to change the position of the notification message unless you go back a few releases

Comment: The location changed recently. I guess it got changed suddenly in between version 35 and 36.

Comment: oh wait, you mean notifications, not error messages/alerts. Are you on beta or dev channel?

Comment: I'm using the stable release. Version 36.0.1985.125 m

Answer (score 5):

This has been [a request for years](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=301848) in Chromium (reported by vadi.ile...@gmail.com, Sep 30 2013):

> Steps to reproduce the problem:
>   1. There is no option to select position for desktop notifications.
>   2. My opinion is for users docked windows taskbar in left right or up, they should be able to select the opision `(sic)` of desktop
>   notifications too.

The final post (comment 18 by awdf@chromium.org, Jan 12, 2018) states:

> Lowering priority since our team's priority is currently to move
>   notifications on all platforms to the respective native notification
>   centres, where supported, and Chrome has no influence over where
>   notifications are displayed by the native notification centres.
>
> On platforms where there is no supported native notification centre
>   (Windows <10 and some Linux variants), we fall back to the Chrome
>   'MessageCentre'-style notifications. For these we do have control on
>   the location of the notifications, so we could in theory do something
>   there, if there is still demand for this issue.

So ATOW (2018-06-13) the priority is low and, if you want Chrome's team to spend some time on this issue on your system (one of those Linux variants, Windows 8.1 or lower) because it's annoying for you, you should voice your opinion there.

Comment: Update: as of 2020-01-15 this feature request is closed as *won't fix*:

"While I appreciate the concerns, we have settled on native notifications as stated in #c18 and we'd recommend you to seek customizability there"

Answer (score 2):

It's not a feature at the moment. On the Chrome forum someone suggested using an extension to do it but I couldn't find one on the Chrome Web Store.

Answer (score 1):

My Chrome has been updated recently to **Version 37.0.2062.102** and the location of the notification message has now set to the top-right corner automatically.

I still don't have the option to change the location yet, but by updating the browser my issue is now fixed.